# Почему gradle дистрибутив версии 2.2, а dependencies 1.0.0?

Tags: gradle

Объясните плз, что имеется в виду под версией гредл в файле
**gradle-wrapper.properties**
строка:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

и зависимость в **buil.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
```

И подскажите как создать в Intellij проект с последней версией гредл потому как тогда я создаю новый проет у меня создается

```
dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.0'
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что версии 2.2.1 - собственно [дистрибутив gradle](http://gradle.org/downloads/) , программа-сборщик проектов ( текущая версия 2.4).
То , что версии 1.0.0 - [плагин для Android Studio\IntelliJ IDEA](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle) (текущая версия 1.2.3).

Сборщик и плагин - разные вещи и они имеют разные версии , плагин нужен для того, чтобы IDE могла управлять сборщиком.

[Здесь](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system) попробуйте найти решение своей проблемы по миграции , хотя оно должно автоматически предлагать последние версии - у меня происходит именно так.

Answer (score 4):

Строка

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

указывает на путь к файлу в интеренете который используется для сборки проекта. Intellij Idea сама подскажет что у вас старая версия gradle в dependencies, и предложит заменить на новую автоматически. 
Строка

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
```

указывает на то, что мы собираем android проект.